# Error while installing sumo-0.21.0 for Veins 3.0

Tags: omnet++

I first build sumo using
`export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/opt/local/include"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/opt/local/lib"
make -f Makefile.cvs
./configure --with-fox-config=/opt/local/bin/fox-config -with-proj-gdal=/opt/local --with-xerces=/opt/local --prefix=/opt/sumo`

then `sudo make install` ends with the following error

**NIImporter_ArcView.cpp:129:49: error: no member named 'Open' in 'OGRSFDriverRegistrar'**

best regards

SG

Answer (score 0):

In `./configure` should be `--with-proj-gdal=/opt/local` (with two dashes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but thats not the problem.

Comment: You probably have gdal 2.0. It seems that sumo-0.21.0 requires gdal in version 1.xx.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. I installed gdal through macports..where and how do i go about installing an older version..Thanks again..

Comment: @essgee I'd suggest asking the SUMO developers as well, if you haven't already, because [the official SUMO documentation](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing/MacOS_Build) suggests to use the version from macports (without disclosing the version). An alternative would be to compile your own gdal version; [the linux guide](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing/Linux_Build) suggests using 1.5 and provides a download link.

Comment: @RensvanderHeijden Thanks Ive addressed this issue to the sumo mailing list. Meanwhile, I don't see a working download link for the gdal-1.5.1.tar.gz package in [the linux guide](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing/Linux_Build).